# Cannot install .ipa created from Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm developing my application in xcode 4.5 and i want to create the `.ipa` file to transfer the project in to client's device. But unfortunately I can't install it in device. Giving a pop up says "Cannot install".

i have created the ipa and installed it from xcode 4.0.2. So i know the process. I thinks i have given correct provisionning  profile too. Is there any reason or anyone can give me a tutorial on this in xcode 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for replies. i found the solution in entitlements.plist file thr is a property called 
get-task-allow. i had to set it to NO.
Tht wat happed with xcode 4.5.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for this info, 
I desperately looked for a solution to this, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Did you build the app with an ad-hoc distribution profile that includes the client's device UDID?

Alteratively, use Testflight which works extremely well for this sort of thing.

Comment: thanks for the reply. ill check on test flight. but. the problem is have to put the app store version this week . i'm afraid tht it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ipa is correct, is the client's device running an OS supported by the ipa (check deployment target of your project)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i have changed the deployment target to the 6.0. still the same issue. itunse sync->cannot install the app

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in the Xcode Organizer console for the device as you perform the install?  There is likely an error message in the console that will give you a clue.

Are there any unsafe characters in the .ipa filename?  I had a case once where iTunes was installing the app and changing the .ipa filename to be the app name.  Well, the app name had a '/' in it, and that doesn't work so well in filenames.  The console showed me the error as it occurred.

If you aren't installing with the device connected to Xcode, you can use the iPhone Configuration Utility to watch/record the console on a remote machine.

Comment: Thanks.As i checked on the log file thr is no error. The problem is i can use the development profile. but cannot use the adhoc